# How to create a UserControl with WinForms based on another UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

**I added some screenshots and steps to reproduce below.**

My data model has a base class, let's call it `CommonThing` which has lots of properties. Then there are several specialized versions of this class with additional properties. I now want to create a UI to input data into this model.

I created a `UserControl` which contains controls for all the common properties like this:

```
internal partial class CommonThingControl : UserControl {

    public CommonThingControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Controller code
}
```

This also adds a `CommonThingControl.Designer.cs` which is populated by the GUI designer.

I now created a `SpecialFooThingControl` as a `UserControl` and changed the class header to read:

```
internal partial class SpecialFooThingControl : CommonThingControl {

    // implementation
}
```

When I now open the `SpecialFooThingControl` in the GUI designer, I see the controls of the `CommonThingControl` but they are all locked. I however have a `TableLayoutPanel` in the `CommonThingControl` I want to add stuff to, but I cannot change anything, and when I try to drag a control into the `TableLayoutPanel` the mouse cursor becomes a "No parking" sign and VS does not let me. This even happens when I set the accessor of the `TableLayoutPanel` to `public`.

I *can* move a control into the `TableLayoutPanel` via the document outline, but when I then rebuild the project, it disappears from the UI.

Is what I am trying to achieve not possible with the UI designer and do I have to set this up by hand or is there some additional step I forgot?

Here is what I did:

First, created a User Control, this is straightforward. I created a table layout panel which I set to `Protected` because I want to add to it.
[image: Common Control]

This is the code for `FooControl.cs`:

```
namespace GuiTest {
    public partial class FooControl : UserControl {
        public FooControl() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And `FooControl.Designer.cs`:

```
namespace GuiTest {
    partial class FooControl {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && (components != null)) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 28);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 7);
            this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 7, 3, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Foo";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(34, 3);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(323, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // FooControl
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.Name = "FooControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 28);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        protected System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Now, I added `BarControl`:
[image: Adding UserControl]

Now I changed the extend from `UserControl` to `FooControl` in `BarControl.cs`:

```
namespace GuiTest {
    public partial class BarControl : FooControl {
        public BarControl() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

`BarControl.Designer.cs`:

```
namespace GuiTest {
    partial class BarControl {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && (components != null)) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And this is how it turns out:
[image: Locked Layout Panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the controls in `CommonThingControl` are locked is because the sub-class `SpecialFooThingControl` doesn't have access to them (they are privately scoped).

What you can do however in the designer for `CommonThingControl` is change the modifiers property on them, which will allow you to consume/modify them in your sub-class. You need to do this on each individual control, and can simply change the dropdown in the Properties window. You can probably change them in the `commonthingcontrol.designer.cs` file however I would also be wary on the basis that this file is auto-generated and changes can easily be over-written if you're not careful.

[image]

I'd recommend using something like `Protected` to ensure they're visible to the sub-controls but prevent them being abused outside of the inheritance chain.

**EDIT**

So further looking into this reveals that this is a limitation of the `TableLayoutPanel`. Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689.aspx:

> Avoid Visual Inheritance The TableLayoutPanel control does not support
>   visual inheritance in the Windows Forms Designer. A TableLayoutPanel
>   control in a derived class appears as "locked" at design time.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but it is still shown as locked. But I am also stuck on VS2010 because I have to interface some third-party libraries that don't work with newer VS versions. Maybe this is a bug in VS 2010.

Comment: @rabejens Have you tried a rebuild/restart Visual Studio? Sometimes that helps believe it or not. If you've got them set to any other than `Private` and your sub-control is in the same project then that really should just work.

Comment: @rabejens could you add a screenshot to further elaborate if that doesn't help?

Comment: A rebuild and restart did not help. Already tried that. But it's not a big deal, the additional things added to the control are only a small number, I can also do this manually.

Comment: @rabejens It'd be nice to follow up and see if we can get an answer to the question though rather than leaving it open?

Comment: I added some screenshots and steps to reproduce.

Comment: @rabejens Updated my answer after giving it a try myself.

Comment: Although not really a "Solution", I am accepting it as one as I now know I need another layout.

Answer (score 0):

Due to controls accessibility, you cannot update them.
To do so, go into your CommonThingControl.Designer.cs, change for exemple `private Button MyButton1` to `protected Button MyButton1`

Comment: And if you rebuild, remove your control `SpecialFooThingControl` and re-add it ?